# How would one conjugate "to be" in southern middle english?

Tags: conjugation, middle-english

Present tense.  In particular, how would it have been in London in the mid-14th century?

Answer (score 3):

At this point you could find the same conjugation as early Modern (not least since the dialect that had the greatest impact on Modern English was here):

> Ich: am.
>
> Þou: art.
>
> He/she/it/one: is.
>
> We/ye/þei: are.

There would be variant spellings (*he ys*, *I ham*), probably more than in early Modern. In subjunctive use you might also find *I be, þou best, he beeþ, we ben*.